# How to properly set up NodeMailer SMTP emailing

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I need to send emails using Node.JS and have been using NodeMailer with Gmail as the service so far. However, I am now required to use a non-Gmail account to continue. I received the following details of the new account: (I've slightly edited it for this thread to remove sensitive information)

**Email Address:** no-reply@service.co.za

**Account / User Name:** no-reply@service.co.za

**Password:** 1234

**Incoming server:** mail.service.co.za

**Outgoing (SMTP) server:** smtp.service.co.za

**SMTP Authentication:** On (same Username as incoming)

**SMTP Port:** 587

My code is as follows:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.service.co.za',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'no-reply@service.co.za',
        pass: '1234'
    }
});

const mailOptions = {
    from: 'Company <no-reply@service.co.za>',
    to: "john@gmail.com",
};
```

Later in my code I add subjects and bodies to the email, depending on the function and send it. I get the following error:

> Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: smtp.service.co.za. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.jnb1.host-h.net"

I've tried quite a few of the solutions in other threads regarding this issue. The only one which works is adding:

```
tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
},
```

But this apparently causes the email to become insecure, which is not a viable solution to me. So could anyone tell me how to properly use all the details of the new account given to me to set up a secure SMTP emailing function using NodeMailer?

Comment: if `service.co.za` isn't *set up* correctly, not much you can do, unless you can make changes to `service.co.za`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: the certificate used by `smtp.service.co.za` looks completely unrelated to that domain - you can't fix that, unless you're the one responsible for that domain

Comment: If this issue is on the server a solution can be enable outgoing SMTP from the server settings. On servers running cPanel WHM, it's in the WHM "Settings Settings" section.

The option is enable / disable - choose disable.

Warning: Making this change will redirect outgoing SMTP connections that allow accounts to make direct connections, which can increase your chances of your server being blacklisted.